# Vim shortcut to build out proper html

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to write my own function to convert a string like this:

```
div.class1.class2#id
```

into an HTML element like this

```
<div class="class1 class2" id="id">|</div>
```

with | representing the cursor.  I've gotten this far, but it produces this with multiple classes:

```
<div class="class1" class="class2" id="id">|</div>
```

Which is to be expected of the code.  The error I'm having is, being new to viml, I don't know the best way to approach this problem in the language.  Any ideas on getting the classes to be space separated?

Also, it's my first viml file, so any comment would be appreciated (especially on the bindings themselves!)

```
function! CompileSelectors (input)
  let element=ParseElement(a:input)
  return '<'.element.'>'.CloseTag(element)
endfunction

function! ParseElement (input)
  let escapedInput=escape(a:input, '^$.*\/~[]')
  let elementWithClass=substitute(escapedInput, '\\\.\([^\.#]*\)', ' class="\1"', 'g')
  let elementWithId=substitute(elementWithClass, '#\([^\.#]*\)', ' id="\1"', 'g')
  return substitute(elementWithId, '\\\([\^\$\.\*\\\/\~\[\]\)', '\1', 'g')
endfunction

function! CloseTag (input)
  return '</'.matchstr(a:input, '\S\+', 0, 1).'>'
endfunction

imap <Leader><Tab> <Esc>vBdi
  \<C-R>=CompileSelectors('<C-r>"')<CR>
  \<Esc><<F<i

imap <Leader><Return> <Esc>vBdi
  \<C-R>=CompileSelectors('<C-r>"')<CR>
  \<Esc><<F<i<Return><Esc>O
```

---

Fixed the title - sorry about that!

Comment: Do you have any good reason for not using emmet, zencoding or sparkup? Well... curiosity would be a good reason, actually, but still... this is a solved problem.

Comment: @romainl I'm aware there are already solutions - I'm just trying to learn how to write them! :)

Comment: Wouldn't your example have to be `div.class1.class2.#id` to yield the output?

Comment: absolutely @IngoKarkat thanks haha

Answer (score 1):

I would have probably parsed the class names into a List, and then use `join()` to put them back together, separated by spaces, but I understand that (especially for a beginner) it's easier to just substitute the string repeatedly.

To continue with your approach, you can just add another substitution that removes intermediate `class=`:

```
let elementWithClass=substitute(elementWithClass, '" class="', ' ', 'g')
```

#### additional comments

- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- You're using global functions, which are prone to name clashes. Especially if you intend to publish this as a plugin eventually, use either script-local (`function! s:CompileSelectors()`, in a mapping use `<SID>CompileSelectors`), or autoload (`function! MyPlugin#CompileSelectors()`) scope.

Comment: I actually was curious how I would go about doing so with the list and join, as even how the statement is now there's a lot of substitution going on! More so than I would like at least.  And thanks for the additional comments! Good points :)